# Casting Parent Class to Child Class to Avoid Redundancy

Tags: c++, inheritance, parent-child, virtual-functions

I have the following classes related to mathematics/geometry: `MathLine`, `MathPoint`, `MathVector`, `MathPlane`.

On each of these, you can perform rotation and translation transformations. So I created a parent class called `GeometricObject`, objects which can be transformed in geometric space.

Now, I am able to created pure virtual class functions with different implementations for each child class. Now, I want a general function which can take `GeometricObject`, but "smartly" return what type I actually put in. For example, I have the following function which rotates a Geometric object to a different coordinate system:

```
GeometricObject rotate_object_to_global_coordinate_system(GeometricObject object) {
  object.rotateX(90);  // Pure virtual functions
  object.rotateY(90);
  object.rotateZ(90);

  return object;
}
```

If I input a MathLine into it, I expect the function to "cast" into a `MathLine`, perform `MathLine`'s implementation of my virtual functions, and return a `MathLine`.

I've searched everywhere for this and it seems like this can be done by using either pointers (`auto_ptr`) or casting (`dynamic_cast`). This doesn't seem good because I've read that it's a bad way to do it because it sacrifices a noticeable amount of performance. It also seems like a simple feature that a high-level programming language should have. Can this be done?

I think it's really important for me to do this because otherwise, I would have to write separate functions which basically perform the same virtual functions for different child classes. I would have to write:

```
MathLine  rotate_line_to_global_coordinate_system(MathLine object);
MathPoint rotate_point_to_global_coordinate_system(MathPoint object);
MathPlane rotate_plane_to_global_coordinate_system(MathPlane object);
// etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what templates are for. Preferably, implement your rotation function as a template that can operate directly on any one of your four subclasses.

If that's not feasible, another, less preferred but a still mostly tolerable option is to take this rotation function and wrap it inside a facade template that forwards its parameter, then takes the return value from the rotation function, casts it to the appropriate type, and then returns it.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your methods are virtual in the mother class, if you call them, it will automatically call the implementation.
Your code may be the following:

```
class GeometricObject
{
    virtual void rotateX(float angle) = 0;
    virtual void rotateY(float angle) = 0;
    virtual void rotateZ(float angle) = 0;
};
```

Then, any function inheriting from this class must have those functions implemented:

```
class MathLine : public GeometricObject
{
    void rotateX(float angle) { /* Implementation */ }
    void rotateY(float angle) { /* Implementation */ }
    void rotateZ(float angle) { /* Implementation */ }
};
```

Now, if you call your function `rotate_object_to_global_coordinate_system` and passing to it a `MathLine`, it will automatically call its implementation of rotation functions.

And if you follow the same rules for other objects, it would do the same for `MathPoint`, `MathPlane`, etc.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've checked this and it doesn't work. Which is why I posted this question in the first place. However, I will double check and let you know. Thank you!

Comment: @RandyArdywibowo Post your code if you want help directly on it.